# can't connect to local internet using wire

Tags: networking, internet

I'm at work right now. there's a Windows pc connected to some sort of shared wired internet ... when I connect that wire to my laptop I can't connect to the internet it keeps connecting and then it just fail to connect showing an error `network disconnected`. 
is there any way I can connect my Ubuntu laptop to this network ? do I have to set an IP or something like that ? 

what I have tired yet is to copy MAC address from Windows pc and type it down when I creat a new ethernet network... also I set IP4 to be automatic.. am I going to the right direction ?

Comment: Sounds like there's some security on the work network, expressly put there to stop you doing that. Have you spoken to whoever's in charge about it? MAC spoofing might get you into the network - or not - but equally might get you in the Job Centre without a reference..

Comment: @MarkWilliams yes true I guess it's somehow protected... but that PC won't be able to connect to that network unless it has some configurations or speical settings like ports or IP... i can't figure how or where to start to get these informations from that PC becasue they must be there!!. the one in charge isn't around as it's weekend duty.. Thanks alot

Comment: It should pick up IP from the router's DHCP - you could legitimately check the old PC's IP & hard-code that one (`sudo ifconfig eth0 10.1.1.1` or whatever), you could scan for router (probably the root of the IP with 1 or 254 as final number), ports should look after themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your network is protected and need to configure your proxy settings. First,

Create Ethernet Network and select Manual Method in your IPv4 settings. Now add *Address, Netmask, Gateway, DNS Servers.*

Go to

> System Settings-->Network-->Network Proxy-->Manual-->add your proxyIP and port

and If you want to get update or access the internet through the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

you'll see

> Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://proxyip:port/";

and if you have a username and password for your proxy then, change it to

> Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyip:port/";
>   Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@proxyip:port/";

I hope this will enable you to connect your network.

Comment: Thank you so much, well explained ... but please could you guide me how to get these informations `Address, Netmask, Gateway, DNS Servers` from that Windows PC ?