# How to resolve 307 proxy redirect in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: apt, 13.10, proxy

Whenever I use apt-get update, it results in an error

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources
307  Proxy Redirect [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
:
:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-
security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  307  Proxy Redirect [IP: 
91.189.91.15 80]
```

This error is repeated for several other packages. I am working from behind a https proxy. I have tried various things based on suggestions in posted in various forums including the following:

1. Set up the details of proxy server in

   I) /etc/apt/apt.conf
   II) /etc/bash.bashrc
   III) /etc/profile
   IV)  Environment variables
2. Change mirror server in /etc/apt/sources.list - all mirrors give the same result. Also everytime I select a new mirror and close, it gives an error "Check your Internet Connection". The internet connection is working fine by the way. I am able to access the sites mentioned in the error message.
3. Another post suggested altering the /etc/apt/sources.list.save file to remove all additional / in all the entries. For eg:

   deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted altered to
   deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted

Still no success. Kindly help as I have exhausted all options I came across online. Also I am a newbie so simplification of the reply would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it useful?....: http://askubuntu.com/questions/596224/cant-connect-to-local-internet-using-wire/596250#596250

Comment: To close voters: even though 13.10 is well past end of life, the answer to this question about APT proxy configuration is likely the same for current Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is setting the proxy as environment variable:

```
$ sudo -i
# export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com/:80
# export https_proxy=...
# apt-get do something
```